# What is this rotting wood 'ledge' around my house? Is replacing it something I can tackle? The outdoor trim too?

Tags: wood, exterior, trim, water-damage

I  have this, for lack of a better word, 'ledge' around the west side of my house ( *I'd call it a drip edge but I doubt that's it* )

**Background:** This sun-room space over the once-garage was an addition to the house long before I moved in.  It is rotting in many places along with the trim around my back door,  Id' like to replace it.

Naively I would expect the process would be:

1. Tear out the old wood with putty knife (for caulking) and whatever else I can use to pry it out (cant see how it's even fastened in)
2. Replace with outdoor-rated, pressure-treated wood
3. Paint with exterior waterproof paint
4. Replace trim with trim Id find at the home center.

**Questions/Issues:**

- What wood should I use, and what paint should I use.
- Still investigating, but any suggestion how it should be fastened in there.
- Biggest issue I see:  not sure how to get the exact size.  Would I have to plane boards to the right thickness?
- Have never replaced door trim before, I see a lot of 'mouldings' and trims in different material. Any recommendations on the material? Type? or what you suggest.  Should I just use bondo or something instead?

[image: Bottom of right side of door trim]
[image: Bottom of left side of door trim]
[image: Back desk rotting wood]
[image: full view of door trim]
[image: corner of this overhang]
[image: another corner of this overhang]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone has a similar odd situation this is what I did:

- tore out the skirt board and this ledge
- the underlying osb sheathing was rotting in parts, cut that out
- some of the underlying framing was even rotting in parts.  Treated this with hardener and filled with bondo wood filler, sprayed down anit-mold for good measure
- replaced old sheating with plywood, sealed with r-guard fast flash
- to meet the thickness of 5/4 old skirtboard I put a layer of zip-system board and sealed it with r-guard flast flash
- put pvc trim board longer than the previous skirt board to make up for this 'ledge'
- sealed with osi guard caulking

issues that Im not happy with:

- the height of the gap changed around the house so it was hard to cut the different boards to the right height and this created gaps that were larger than I wanted in areas required to be filled with caulking more than it should be
- the z channel drip edge was bent a lot during the removal and replacement, probably should have tried to replace it, but I just tried to bang it back into place

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Joe, good job.
What you repaired is called a "skirt board" or in other forms a "water table".

Here is a web site where the author built his own similar to you, ripping, mitering, and glueing up Azek components.  He dealt with some of the issues you bring up. 
[Building Traditional Water Table Trim With Cellular PVC Lumber](https://hammerzone.com/archives/exterior/trim/water_table/pvc.htm)

There are various ready made PVC products that might match your application.  Here is one:
https://azekexteriors.com/products/trim/skirt-boards-bands/universal-skirt-board

Answer (score 0):

Just a warning : getting the details right is hard.  Getting a experienced handy person involved may be your best bet.  Your area may require a building permit.

At your corner, and perhaps in other areas, you may end up needing to leave some rotted wood in place.  The standard of care is to wire brush as much rot away as possible and treat the area.

I like "Smiths Penetrating Epoxy", CPES, for this purpose http://www.smithandcompany.org/ as it penetrates deeply, stabilizing the rot.  Once cured it has no smell.

Use of wood preservative is possible here also, but there's a persistent smell that can last for decades.

You don't need to reshape the wood, just to kill and arrest the fungus
[image: Stabilizing rotted wood that must be left in place. Smiths Epoxy]